# Как отслеживать каждый созданный объект по отдельности?

Tags: c#, unity3d

По клику на кнопку создаётся куб, и его нужно через 2 секунды удалить. И так с каждым кубом по отдельности, но как отследить отдельный куб я не знаю.

```
public GameObject cubePrefab; //Ссылка на префаб куба


public void OnClick()
{
   Instantiate(cubePrefab);
   //Здесь должен быть код, отслеживающий каждый созданный куб по отдельности
   Invoke("Delete", 2f)
}

void Delete() //Не работает так как нету части кода в котором отслеживается каждый куб по отдельности
{
   Destroy();
}
```

Comment: Не знаю конечно, что там в юнити, не работал с ним. Но вам не кажется, что за свое состояние должен отвечать сам объект (куб)? Я бы по кнопке лишь создавал его, а сам куб при инициализации запускал бы таймер для удаления.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Что-то подобное я и хочу сделать. Как вариант создать отдельный скрипт для куба, при инициализации которого он начинал бы отсчёт

Comment: По коду я вижу, что вы пишете все в одном месте, там, где клик кнопки) Сделайте отдельный скрипт, повесьте его на куб, там стартуйте его удаление при инициализации, ну а по клику, просто создавайте куб.

Answer (score 1):

Создать скрипт куба. Вешать на куб при спавне, а еще лучше создать префаб куба с уже навешенными скриптом:

```
public class Cube {
    private float LifeTime = 2;
    public void Update () {
        LifeTime -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (LifeTime <= 0) 
            Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Или:

```
public class Cube {
    private float LifeTime;
    public void Start () {
        StartCoroutine(Life());
    }
    private IEnumerator Life () {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(LifeTime);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

просто сохраняй ссылку на созданный объект, например так

```
public GameObject cubePrefab;
private GameObject cube;

public void OnClick()
{
   cube = Instantiate(cubePrefab);
   Invoke("Delete", 2f);
}

void Delete()
{
   Destroy(cube);
}
```